# Eclipse StatEt echo every line twice?

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

Here is the code I tried to send to R console in Eclipse:

```
distuni = setRefClass("DistUniform", 
        c("a", "b"),
        methods = list(
                mean = function() {
                    (a+b)/2
                }
                )
        )
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

As you can see, every line is echoed twice, very annoying. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: What OS and Java do you use?

Comment: Kubuntu 14.04, openjdk 7

Comment: Try oracle java http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-installing-oracle-java7-on-ubuntu-linux/